# What are the supported code points for 'special characters' for valid z/OS datasets?

Tags: dataset, zos

I want to validate a dataset name in my C code on z/OS. The @, #, $, - characters are valid characters as per: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=sets-data-set-naming-rules
What I am not sure is if those special characters are invariant across all EBCDIC code pages? If I look at code page 1047: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Character_Encodings/Code_Tables/EBCDIC/EBCDIC_1047
it lists the $ symbol at 0x5B but I am not sure if it is invariant across all EBCDIC code pages.

Same question for @, #, -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is confusing because the "national characters" '@#$' have the same code points but different character symbols in different EBCDIC pages.  They're displayed differently in different code pages, but the same three code ***points*** are what are supported in data set names, regardless of code page.  It's hard to find general information about EBCDIC in the IBM manuals, but there's a note about the national characters in the JCL Reference at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=parameters-character-sets explaining that the characters supported are specifically "the U.S. National characters; @ as X'7C'; $ as X'5B'; and # as X'7B'" and lookalike characters on other countries' terminals may cause errors.

Hyphen '-' and all the other special characters used in JCL, on the other hand, should be invariant in all EBCDIC code pages.  I haven't found documentation saying so, but they're the same in all the code pages documented for the CMS Pipelines XLATE stage. (Figure 401 at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/SSB27U_7.3.0/pdf/c2462521.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the JCL reference - that was what I was missing. The other books refer to actual glyphs vs code points and the code points are a more precise way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Glenn's answer, I just used a terminal emulator to check about 25 different code pages, and while the appearance of most of the special characters available on my USA keyboard don't change with a code page change, the characters ~ ! { } [ ] | \ ^ do tend to change.  These of course don't matter for the original question about MVS datasets, but they do come into play in other areas such as C programming.

Comment: Yes - Long long ago I added support for pragma filetag to the C compiler on z/OS to deal with the variant characters for the C language on z/OS in EBCDIC. Not a problem in ASCII - they are all invariant.

Answer (score 2):

All the special characters are not invariant across EBCDIC code pages.  For example, `@` is usually `0x7C` (e.g. in IBM-1047) , but is `0xB5` in some German codepages, such as 273/1141.

Comment: Yes - that’s what I thought. It seems the docs are in error that talk about glyphs (eg #) and they should really reference code points ?

Answer (score 2):

As others have said they are not all invariant. I found [this paper](https://www.unicode.org/wg2/docs/n1848.doc) (.doc warning) to be elucidating when learning more about EBCDIC invariant and variants. Specifically, section 2.1

> Characters such as #, @, and $ are also allowed in file names.  While
> the invariance of the 81 characters of the IBM Syntactic Character Set
> (with IBM Graphic Character Set Global Identifier - GCSGID 640) is
> assumed (with some known exceptions), characters such as #, @, and $
> are known to be variant among existing EBCDIC-coded character sets.
> Irrespective of whether a larger character set is permitted in file
> management related entities, the core set of characters is hard-coded
> in traditional file systems and in many applications -- see Figure 3
> on page 12.

And Figure 3

[image]

All the National Characters (@$#) are variant. However the special character hyphen "-" appears to be invariant.

If you can [find the CCSID of your input](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=correctly-finding-ccsid-values-your-data-sources) you can use Unicode services to convert to an "application standard" if needed. This seems like it would be a common issue developing in a mixed environment and potentially solved already.

Comment: Two surprises there in code points I might have expected to be invariant:

* x'41' is usually nonbreaking space, but the APL page (SET APL ON on VM) has the underlined alphabet starting there.

* x'c0' is valid in data set names (but not catalog entries, so it can only be used in uncataloged data sets) and member names.  It's a left-bracket in some pages, and a different-shaped left-bracket in APL, but a letter with a diacritic in others.  The [JCL Reference](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=definition-unqualified-name) specifies it as "a character X'C0'", not by appearance.

Comment: @glenn That's interesting I didn't know about x'c0' in uncataloged data set names.

Answer (score 0):

This is a snippet from some code I wrote to validate a dataset name.  Before calling this routine I translate all periods to blanks into a new variable called tdsn. Hope this helps. It may be crude but it works for my purposes.

```
 /* ------------------------------------------- *        
 | Process each 'word' within the dataset name |         
 |   - not greater than 8 characters           |         
 |   - starts with a valid character           |         
 |   - contents are valid                      |         
 * ------------------------------------------- */        
 do dsnvi = 1 to words(tdsn)                             
   w = word(tdsn,dsnvi)                                  
   if length(w) > 8 then return 'INVALID'                
   if pos(left(w,1),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ$#@') = 0 
   then return 'INVALID'                                 
   w = translate(w,left(' ',40,' '), ,                   
     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-$#@0123456789')         
   w = strip(w)                                          
   if w /= '' then return 'INVALID'                      
 end
```

Comment: A nice example - what I was curious about though was the code points for the special characters $#@-